# Add a subclass of subview to a subclass of UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm trying to do something very basic. I want to add a subView to my UIView subclass. I assume that I would put this in initWithFrame method as below, but view that are instances of this class do not draw this subview. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        redView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 20, 20)];
        [redView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self addSubview:redView];
    }

    return self;
}
```

BTW redView is a property defined in the header of the sub class, like:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *redView;
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Code looks ok. Try setting self.backgroundColor to green to see if it shows up.

Comment: actually initWithFrame does not fire. I am assigning elements in a storyboard to this subclass...

Comment: How do you alloc init that view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should place your initializing code inside:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder { ... }
```

or

```
- (void)awakeFromNib { ... }
```

These methods are called when a view is loaded from nib. Don't forget to call [super ...] in the above methods.

Comment: This is only a partial answer; it happened to work because the OP was apparently using NIBs. The more correct answer is to perform the initialization in a method that is called from initWithCoder *and* initWithFrame; that will cover both programmatic and NIB loading.